# Ruby map! does not change contained variable

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an object `x`, and an array `y=[x]` which contains `x`. If I manipulate `x`, then `y` does not change:

```
x = 1 # => 1
y = [x] # => [1]
x = x+1 # => 2
x # => 2
y # => [1]
```

and if I change `y`, then `x` does not change.

```
x = 1 # => 1
y = [x] # => [1]
y.map!{|a| a+1} # => [2]
y # => [2]
x # => 1
```

Is there a way to have them change in parallel? It feels like when I `map!` over an array the underlying values should change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is the behaviour I want possible? It feels like the whole point of mutating methods is that they change the object the reference is assigned to. So when I `map!` over `y`, `y` is pointing to a different object after the fact. I appreciate that this is more transparent, but that sounds like a counterargument to having mutator methods in the first place.

Comment: You're confused about what mutating methods apply to. `map!` is a mutating method for the array. Array is changed (by constructing a new set of numbers)

Comment: Numbers are immutable, and there's a reason for that. Changing a value somewhere and having it also 'magically' change somewhere else can lead to program behavior that's hard to follow and even harder to debug.

Comment: "So when I map! over y, y is pointing to a different object after the fact" - no, it isn't. `y` will point to the very __same__ array object (but which now holds different content). Big difference.

Comment: The only way to have two variables (not objects) "change in parallel" is by using global variables and `alias`. It's an odd feature and you usually don't want to do that.

Comment: @Stefan It's interesting that you say not objects. The original reason I came across this problem is that I have an object with an accessor variable which, for certain purposes, needs to be wrapped in an array and mapped over. If I make `args` an array-instance-variable and map over it, I get the desired behaviour (the array changes), while if I wrap the `arg` variable in an array and map over the array, then `arg` does not change. I understand why Ruby works this way but I think it's perfectly natural if you think of variables as properties of an object.

Answer (score 3):

first of all

```
x = x + 1
```

will create a new variable with an old name `x`

```
x = 1
y = [x]
x.object_id
# 3
y[0].object_id
# 3
x = x + 1
x.object_id
# 5
y[0].object_id
# 3
```

Second, numbers are immutable objects in Ruby (and Strings, for example, are mutable). So you just can't do what you want using number objects in Ruby. What you can do is slightly more obscure. You can create your own mutable object (container for a number) and use a reference to this object in your array.

```
class MutableNumber
  attr_accessor :n

  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
  end
end

x = MutableNumber.new(1)
y = [x]
y[0].n
#=> 1
x.n += 1
y[0].n
#=> 2
```

You can go little bit further and to add more magic here to mimic numbers

```
class MutableNumber
  attr_accessor :n

  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &blk)
    @n = @n.send(m, *args, &blk)
    self
  end
end

x = MutableNumber.new(1)
y = [x]
y[0].n
#=> 1
x += 1
y[0].n
#=> 2
```

But I would not encourage you to do any of this.

Just stick to the idea that numbers are immutable. And overall you should be careful with mutability.

Comment: "But I would encourage you to do any of this." - is there a "not" missing there?

Answer (score 1):

`map!` is mutable for the array, not for its elements. It means that the array gets new values in place (i.e. it's assigned to original array). Elements inside the array are not mutated, but replaced by new elements.

If you want to change old values, you can iterate using `each` and call mutating methods on each element. You can see this with array of strings:

```
a = "a"; b = "b"; aa = [a, b]
#=> ["a", "b"]
aa.map!{|e| e.capitalize }
#=> ["A", "B"]
[a, b]
#=> ["a", "b"]

a = "a"; b = "b"; aa = [a, b]
#=> ["a", "b"]
aa.each{|e| e.capitalize! }
#=> ["A", "B"]
[a, b]
#=> ["A", "B"]
```

Note that it won't work for immutable objects and numbers are immutable, as @fl00r explained in his answer.

Comment: I thought you were motivating me to improve it ;-). Naughty downvoter - not even left a comment...